# How to save JSON array with objects inside Rails JSON column?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Kitchen model and I want to add menu list called `special_kitchen_menus` into it.

I can update the kitchen. But, I get this when I `console.log()` the result from database:

```
[{&quot;name&quot;=&gt;&quot;pizza&quot;, &quot;price&quot;=&gt;29}, {&quot;name&quot;=&gt;&quot;burger&quot;, &quot;price&quot;=&gt;24}, {&quot;name&quot;=&gt;&quot;cake&quot;, &quot;price&quot;=&gt;39}]
```

Line of code that do the console.log()

```
var a = "<%= @kitchen.special_kitchen_menus %>";
console.log(a);
```

I try to use `serialize` and create my own method called `convert_to_hash`. But I got no luck at all.

**schema.rb**

```
create_table "kitchens", force: :cascade do |t|
    # other columns
    t.json     "special_kitchen_menus",  default: {}
end
```

**kitchen model**

```
class Kitchen < ActiveRecord::Base
    # serialize :special_kitchen_menus

    # def convert_to_hash
    #   self.special_kitchen_menus = self.special_kitchen_menus.to_h
    # end
end
```

**kitchen controller**

```
# before_action :convert_to_hash, only: [:update]

def update
    @kitchen = Kitchen.find(params[:id])
    if @kitchen.update(kitchen_params)
      redirect_to @kitchen
    else
      render :edit
    end
end

def kitchen_params
    params.require(:kitchen).permit(:special_kitchen_menus)
end
```

**form**

```
<%= form_for @kitchen do |f| %>
    <!-- other fields -->

    <label>Special Kitchen Menus</label>
    <%= f.text_field :special_kitchen_menus %>              
    <%= f.submit "Update" %>
<% end %>
```

**sample data for update**

```
[
  { "name": "pizza", "price": 29 }, 
  { "name": "burger", "price": 24 }, 
  { "name": "cake", "price": 39 }
]
```

What should I do to update the input data correctly so that I can retrieve it back correctly just the input data without that weird characters?

**Note 1**: I don't want to store the data in another model OR use nested attribute. I just want to store the data inside this Kitchen model using the same Kitchen's form.

**Note 2**: I'm using postgres database. Not sqlite for this app.

Comment: Can you show us the line of codes the has the `console.log` statement?

Comment: Just update my question. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var a = <%= @kitchen.special_kitchen_menus.to_json.html_safe %>;
console.log(a);
```

Comment: Hard to find answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can save JSON array in JSON type column. In the JSON type column, you can only store ***VALID JSON*** object. As, array of JSON is not a JSON object, so you should not be able to store that in a json column in Rails. Postgres has an [array column type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/arrays.html). You should use that to store array of JSON objects instead.

#### Update

You can use [jsonb](http://nandovieira.com/using-postgresql-and-jsonb-with-ruby-on-rails) column type to store array of JSON objects in the database. Take a look at this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36103968/a-rails-field-that-is-an-array-of-json-objects) pointed by @brg in the comment section.

Comment: Could you please suggest what should I do now?

Comment: are you on postgres or mysql?

Comment: postgres has array column type that you can use:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/arrays.html

Comment: You can save JSON ARRAY in jsonb type column. see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36103968/a-rails-field-that-is-an-array-of-json-objects  and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38679190/query-jsonb-column-containing-array-of-json-objects