# Query jsonb column containing array of JSON objects

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activerecord, jsonb

I use **PostgreSQL 9.5** and Rails 5. I want to query the `jsonb` column shown below that holds an array of JSON objects to return all the JSON array element containing `{"kind":"person"}` and also perform a count.
The **SQL** I use is shown below the json data. Running the query just returns an empty array.

I have tried the queries suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22736742/query-for-array-elements-inside-json-type) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10560394/how-do-i-query-using-fields-inside-the-new-postgresql-json-datatype/10560761#10560761).

This is what my `jsonb` data looks like:

```
   '[
        {"kind":"person", "filter_term":"56","selected_attr":"customer"},
        {"kind":"email", "filter_term":"marketer","selected_attr":"job_title"}
      ]'
```

I want one of the sql query to return:

```
                             data
----------------------------------------------------------------------
 '{"kind":"person", "filter_term":"56","selected_attr":"customer"}'
(1 row)
```

and another query to return array back so that I can call count on it in my app and also loop over it to create forms:

```
 data
----------------------------------------------------------------------
 '[{"kind":"person", "filter_term":"56","selected_attr":"customer"}]'
 (1 row)
```

I tried this SQL query:

```
 "SELECT * FROM \"segments\" WHERE (payload @> '[{\"kind\":\"person\"}]')"
```

I also tried this query:

```
  "SELECT payload FROM segments WHERE payload @> '[{\"kind\":\"person\"}]'::jsonb;"
```

Here is a 3rd query:

```
 "SELECT * FROM segments s WHERE s.payload->'\"#{a}\"' @> '[{\"kind\":\"person\"}]';"
```

The model:

```
class Segment < ApplicationRecord
 store_accessor :payload,:kind, :filter_term, :selected_model_name, :selected_attr, :limit, :selected_operator
end
```

The migration:

```
create_table "segments", force: :cascade do |t|

  t.jsonb    "payload",    default: "[]", null: false
  t.index ["payload"], name: "index_segments_on_payload", using: :gin

end
```

Comment: `=>`is valid syntax for [`hstore`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/hstore.html), but not for `json` (or `jsonb`). A valid json literal: `'{"kind":"person"}'` Please fix your example and add what your expected result would look like. *"all the json"* is a bit fuzzy. And there is a table row, there is also the data type `json`, but what is a *"json row"*? You mean JSON array element?

Comment: Many thanks for helping out. Yes I meant a JSON array element. I have rephrased the question to make it clearer hopefully.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assuming this table definition:

```sql
CREATE TABLE segments (segments_id serial PRIMARY KEY, payload jsonb);
```

With JSON values like this:

```sql
INSERT INTO segments (payload)
VALUES ('[
            {
                "kind": "person",
                "limit": "1",
                "filter_term": "56",
                "selected_attr": "customer",
                "selected_operator": "less_than"
            },
            {
                "kind": "email",
                "filter_term": "marketer",
                "selected_attr": "job_title",
                "selected_operator": "equals"
            }
        ]'
   );
```

- You want to return elements of a JSON array that contain the key/value pair `"kind":"person"` (not a nested JSON object `{"kind":"person"}`) - and count array elements as well as table rows (there may be multiple matching array elements per row).

### Solutions

To get the ***count of rows*** containing a qualifying `jsonb` value in column `segments`:

```sql
SELECT count(*)
FROM   segments s
WHERE  s.payload @> '[{"kind":"person"}]';
```

To get ***all qualifying JSON array elements*** (being JSON objects themselves) - plus the total count of elements (may be greater than above count at the same time:

```sql
SELECT j.*
FROM   segments s
JOIN   LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(s.payload) j(elem) ON j.elem @> '{"kind":"person"}'
WHERE  s.payload @> '[{"kind":"person"}]';
```

Returns:

```
elem
------------------------------------------------------------
{"kind": "person", "limit": "1", "filter_term": "56", ... }
```

To get ***all at once***:

```sql
SELECT j.*, count(*) OVER () AS ct_elem, s.ct_rows
FROM  (
   SELECT payload, count(*) OVER () AS ct_rows
   FROM   segments
   WHERE  payload @> '[{"kind":"person"}]'
   ) s
JOIN   LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(s.payload) j(elem) ON j.elem @> '{"kind":"person"}';
```

Returns (for a table with more entries):

```
elem                      | ct_elem | ct_rows
--------------------------+---------+---------
{"kind": "person",  ... } | 4       | 3
{"kind": "person",  ... } | 4       | 3
...
```

But ***I think you really want this***:

```sql
SELECT a.*
     , sum(ct_elem_row) OVER () AS ct_elem_total
     , count(*)         OVER () AS ct_rows
FROM   segments s
JOIN   LATERAL (
   SELECT json_agg(j.elem) AS filtered_payload, count(*) AS ct_elem_row
   FROM   jsonb_array_elements(s.payload) j(elem)
   WHERE  j.elem @> '{"kind":"person"}'
   ) a ON ct_elem_row > 0
WHERE  s.payload @> '[{"kind":"person"}]';
```

Returns (for a table with more entries):

```
filtered_payload                                     | ct_elem_row | ct_elem_total | ct_rows
-----------------------------------------------------+-------------+---------------+---------
[{"kind": "person", ... }]                           | 1           | 4             | 3
[{"kind": "person", ... }]                           | 1           | 4             | 3
[{"kind": "person", ... }, {"kind": "person", ... }] | 2           | 4             | 3
```

This identifies matching rows, then select matching array elements and builds an array per row with only those. Plus counts.

For best performance you would have a `jsonb_path_ops` GIN index like:

```sql
CREATE INDEX segments_path_ops_gin_idx ON segments 
USING  gin (payload jsonb_path_ops);
```

(But a more generic index to serve more different queries may be a better choice.)

Related:

- [Index for finding an element in a JSON array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18404055/index-for-finding-an-element-in-a-json-array/18405706#18405706)
- [Query for array elements inside JSON type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22736742/query-for-array-elements-inside-json-type/22737710#22737710)
- [Best way to get result count before LIMIT was applied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156114/best-way-to-get-result-count-before-limit-was-applied/8242764#8242764)

**Terminology**

We are dealing with a JSON object *containing* a JSON array, saved as Postgres `jsonb` data type - a "JSON array" for short, but *not* an "array of JSON".

Comment: Thank you  so much for the detailed explanation and for the generosity of sharing your knowledge.

Comment: I am happy to change my data to the form in your answer, but just to clarify, is it a wrong design to store the json objects the way I originally did,  similar to first link you referred me to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18404055/index-for-finding-an-element-in-a-json-array/18405706#18405706, where you suggested this query **SELECT * FROM tracks WHERE artists @> '[{"name": "The Dirty Heads"}]';** . If I adapt that query to  **"SELECT * FROM segments WHERE payload @> '[{\"kind\": \"person\"}]';"** to test with my original json which is similar to theirs it returns empty result.

Comment: I just looked at my question and saw why you think I was nesting under a key  like this **'{"a": [{ }, { }] }'** like you did because I had **a=** before the json objects in my question. So I have removed that from my question because my current data is exactly like the one in the first link you referred me to. That is **'[{ }, { }]'**. I am referring to the link in my first comment which is above this comment.

Comment: @brg: I simplified accordingly.

Comment: I ran each sql directly on the database through psql. The first query for count works as expected by returning the correct count. But all the other queries just  returned **(0 rows)** instead of the expected response shown in your example. So I ran **SELECT * FROM segments;** and copied what the database returned and pasted it here so you can see the exact table and its content: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1416f3fe748c792e85047a8d42d8fc3f

Comment: @brg: I tested with pg 9.5 and my queries work as advertised. The column `payload` in the gist you link to have incorrectly escaped double quotes.

Comment: Ok I will remove and re-insert the data. Thanks and enjoy your day.

Comment: Hopefully someone is still watching this thread! I've got a column with an array of JSONB objects, I was trying to run the query like this:

SELECT id,link,users_in_photo FROM "Posts" p WHERE p.users_in_photo @> '[{"username":"arsloan73"}]' LIMIT 1;

And received this:

"[" must introduce explicitly-specified array dimensions.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here... any suggestions?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Hello. I am confused with `SELECT json_agg(j.elem) AS filtered_payload`. So I opened a new question, can you please spare sometime check it.... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69447276/not-understand-json-agg-in-this-context