# jsonb cross join did not return N*M rows in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, jsonb, cross-join

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
                         id int,
                         user_id text,
                         changes jsonb,
                         exercise_entry_id int
);

INSERT INTO mytable VALUES
                        (1, 'foo', '["a","b"]', 3),
                        (2, 'foo', '["c","d"]', 3);
```

Cross join query:

```
SELECT
        mytable.*,
        elems
    FROM
        mytable  cross  join
        jsonb_array_elements(changes) as elems
    order by mytable.id;
```

But this query returns only 4 rows as the picture attached. Cross join should return 8 rows. Now only return 4 rows, what point did i miss?
[image: crossjoin]

Comment: It's a **lateral** cross join so it returns each row from the "base" table as many times as there are elements in the array from that row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query returns 8 rows which is the Cartesian product of `mytable` rows (2) and all elements of all arrays `changes` (4):

```sql
select
    mytable.*,
    elems
from mytable  
cross join (
    select jsonb_array_elements(changes) as elems
    from mytable
    ) s
order by id;
```

Compare it with the lateral join of a subquery (returns 4 rows):

```sql
select
    mytable.*,
    elems
from mytable  
cross join lateral (
    select jsonb_array_elements(changes) as elems
    ) s
order by id;
```

The subquery may be replaced by a simple function call, in which case the word `lateral` is optional.

Find the detailed explanation [in the documentation.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-FROM)

Answer (score 1):

It's lateral cross join. I find it on manual.

> When a FROM item contains LATERAL cross-references, evaluation
> proceeds as follows: for each row of the FROM item providing the
> cross-referenced column(s), or set of rows of multiple FROM items
> providing the columns, the LATERAL item is evaluated using that row or
> row set's values of the columns. The resulting row(s) are joined as
> usual with the rows they were computed from. **This is repeated for each**
> **row or set of rows from the column source table(s)**.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a table function in the `FROM` clause, it is implicitly a `LATERAL` join, so it will join each row with the function results for that row.

See [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#id-1.5.6.6.5.10.2):

> Table functions appearing in `FROM` can also be preceded by the key word LATERAL, but for functions the key word is optional; the function's arguments can contain references to columns provided by preceding FROM items in any case.

Comment: Can you help me  on this question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69447276/not-understand-json-agg-in-this-context) ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help to achieve your needs

```
with temp as
(
 select jsonb_array_elements( changes)    from mytable
)
select * from mytable m1
cross join temp
```

The result:
[image]